# Dissolve shapefile polygons on SQL Management Studio 18

Tags: sql, geometry, dissolve, geography

This is the first time I am trying to work with a shapefile on SQL and I am a little lost.
I uploaded a shapefile with all the counties of the US and what I am trying to do is  to dissolve all counties within California.
After a lot of research I though I could use `UnionAggregate` but when I try to run the query I get an error:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: geometry is incompatible with geography.
```

Any suggestions?

My code:

```
select statefp,geography::UnionAggregate(geom) 
from tl_2017_us_county
where statefp=6
```

Comment: Once you upload a shapefile, which is a file-based geodata standard, into a database table, it's no longer a shapefile. Please [Edit] the question to specify the exact SQL Server release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your geometry column (`geom`) is of type `geometry` and you have told SQLServer to use the `geography` version of the `UnionAggregate` function explicitly by adding `geography::` to it.

I don't have an SQLServer instance handy but the following should work:

```
select statefp, geometry::UnionAggregate(geom) 
from tl_2017_us_county
where statefp=6
```